# Transformation of Payload to custom object using DataWeave 2.0

Tags: json, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

I have an input payload (json array) that needs to be enriched with a custom format.

Input payload:

```
{
  "report": [
    {
      "totPills": 100,
      "food": "chm",
      "drink": "kgf",
      "202201": 1,
      "202202": null,
      "202203": 0.39
    },
    {
      "totPills": 100,
      "food": "mkm",
      "drink": "wfl",
      "202201": 0.0,
      "202202": 1.36,
      "202203": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

In above payload properties `202201`,`202202`,`202203` are dynamic properties.

Expected output:

```
{
  "totPills": 100,
  "report": [
    {
      "food": "chm",
      "drink": "kgf",
      "qty": {
        "202201": 1,
        "202202": null,
        "202203": 0.39
      }
    },
    {
      "food": "mkm",
      "drink": "wfl",
      "qty": {
        "202201": 0.0,
        "202202": 1.36,
        "202203": 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried following Script to get above results (it does not provide expected result):

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Strings
output application/json

var dynWeek = "'202201','202202','202203'"

var pl = payload.report default[] map ((item, index) -> item - 'totPills' )
var pl1 = pl default [] map(($ default {}) mapObject ((value, key, index) -> {
    ((key):value) if ((dynWeek contains((key as String))) == false)
}) )
var pl2 = pl default [] map(($ default {}) mapObject ((value, key, index) -> {
    ((key):value) if ((dynWeek contains((key as String))))
}) )

---
{
    "totPills": payload.report[0].totPills,
    "report":pl1 ++ pl2 /* Not producing expected results */
}
```

I have a few questions:

1. How to achieve the **Expected Output** dynamically?
2. Is there any **performance** impact in this approach?

Thanks,
Rick

Comment: When you say `202201,202202,202203` these are dynamic. Does it mean that you can get `202204,202205` as well? If so, how are you setting the `dynWeek` var?

Comment: No, not like that. These dynamic properties are coming in resultset from SQL Query. We don't know these properties as these can be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I separated the mapping of `report` into two sets of key-values, whose keys are in dynWeek, and those who aren't.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var dynWeek = ['202201','202202','202203']

fun getInList(obj: Object, list: Array, in: Boolean)= obj filterObject ( 
    do {
        var isIn = list contains ($$ as String)
        ---
        if (in) isIn else !isIn
    }
)
---
{
    "totPills": payload.report[0].totPills,
    "report": payload.report 
                map ({
                        (getInList($ - "totPills", dynWeek, false)), // fields not in dynWeek
                        qty: getInList($, dynWeek, true)  // fields in dynWeek
                    })
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "totPills": 100,
  "report": [
    {
      "food": "chm",
      "drink": "kgf",
      "qty": {
        "202201": 1,
        "202202": null,
        "202203": 0.39
      }
    },
    {
      "food": "mkm",
      "drink": "wfl",
      "qty": {
        "202201": 0.0,
        "202202": 1.36,
        "202203": 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Just to check ```dynWeek``` is a comma separated string but you took it as an array. Do I need to first convert it to an Array? Also, it'll be helpful if you'd provide your inputs on performance.

Comment: Using contains() in a string can led to incorrect results. For example string `2201','20` would be considered a key contained in `dynWeek`. Using an array is the correct approach. I forgot to add the conversion in my answer. You could use something like `var dynWeek = "'202201','202202','202203'" replace  "'" with "" splitBy  ","` but I recommend to treat it like a list from the beginning if possible. I don't believe there is any significant performance impact. Note that the only way to be sure is to benchmark.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I am asking for performance here we're dealing around 7Mil records from Azure SQL DB. We're doing transformation in ```Process API``` and I have to consider the performance.

Comment: There doesn't seem anything that at first blush looks to be performance heavy in the script, like for example a join. Having said that, it is very hard to say just by looks. Also in my experience the context where the script executes is usually more important than the script itself. Testing with realistic conditions is the way. One tip I can share is that if you are going to to process the output of the script then use output application/java.

Comment: I tried both application/json and application/java as per your suggestions in both cases API is throwing timedout with 1Mil records. I executed the query directly in database and noticed that DB is taking less than a second to retrieve the records. So, we encountered a performance issue. Any recommendation to improve the performance not exactly in script may be in the approach. Currently, we're using Store Procedures to get the data and then transform the result to return back to EXP API.

Comment: Opened another question for performance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72386419/best-way-to-get-results-designing-mulesoft-api-without-having-any-performance-is

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    "totPills": payload.report[0].totPills,
    "report": payload.report map {
        food: $.food,
        drink: $.drink,
        qty: ($ - "food" - "drink" - "totPills")
    }
}
```

Comment: definitely it provides the result near to my requirements. But, it does not meet the exact requirements. We have specific dynamic properties in comma separated string and we need to map the same in array of qty. For me, the solution you suggested - is added few extra lines for me: 1. I need to explicitly define the property name while enriching the payload. 2. qty array will not contain every dynamic property that we have in comma separated string. I upvoted your answer.