# Getting timeout in a Mule application while processing the output of a big DB query

Tags: sql-server, mule, anypoint-studio, mule4, mule-connector

We've around 7 million records in Azure SQL DB. We have created a stored procedure to fetch paginated records. Following is the script:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetCommodityReport]
(
    @pgNum AS INT = 1,
    @recPerPg AS INT = 100,
    @factory AS NVARCHAR(max) = null,
    @filter AS NVARCHAR(max) = null,
    @isoWYF as VARCHAR(50) = null,
    @isoWYT as VARCHAR(50) = null,
    @columns as NVARCHAR(max) = null,
    @measureCol AS NVARCHAR(max) = null
)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE 
        @where AS NVARCHAR(2000),
        @SQL AS NVARCHAR(max),
        

--sanitize local variables
SET @factory = ISNULL(@factory,'')
SET @filter = ISNULL(@filter,'')
SET @isoWYF = ISNULL(@isoWYF,'')
SET @isoWYT = ISNULL(@isoWYT,'')
SET @measureCol = ISNULL(@measureCol, '[food_qty]')


    SET @where = '[cal_year_week] BETWEEN ' +char(39)+ @isoWYF +char(39) + ' AND ' + char(39) + @isoWYT + char(39)

    IF(@factory != '')
    BEGIN
        SET @where  = '[factory] IN ' + @factory + ' AND ' + @where
    END

    -- apply filters if requested
    IF(@filter != '')
    BEGIN
        SET @where = @where + ' AND ' + @filter
    END

    --Prepare dynamic query

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT ((totRec/' + CAST(@recPerPg AS VARCHAR(100)) + ') +1) [totPg],' + CAST( @PgNum AS VARCHAR(100)) +' [currPg],'+ CAST(@RecPerPg AS VARCHAR(100)) +' [recPerPg], * FROM ('
    
    SET @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT  * '
    
    SET @SQL =  @SQL +  ' from 
    (SELECT 
        count(*) over() [totRec]
        ,[rec_no]
        ,[factory]
,[city]
        ,[food]     
        ,[drink]
        ,[ingre]     
        ,[cal_year_week]
        ,' + @measureCol +
        ',[audit_region]   
        FROM [dbo].[TBLFOOD] WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE'

            + @where

    SET @SQL = @SQL + ') as SRC PIVOT(SUM('+ @measureCol +') for [cal_year_week] in ('+ @columns +')) as PVT) AS FOODTBL '

    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' ORDER BY factory'
    
    if(@recPerPg > 0)
        BEGIN
            SET @SQL = @SQL + '  OFFSET ' + CAST( @recPerPg * (@pgNum - 1) AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' ROWS '
            SET @SQL = @SQL + '  FETCH NEXT ' + CAST( @recPerPg  AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' ROWS ONLY;'
        END


print(@SQL)
EXEC(@SQL)

END
```

In `SYS API` we enrich the response and our `EXP API` is being consumed by front-end app. We don't have `Process API` in this project.

We're doing transformation which is discussed here: [Transformation of Payload to custom object using DataWeave 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72370599/transformation-of-payload-to-custom-object-using-dataweave-2-0)

This is working as expected in `dev` environment where we have around `50k` records. When we promote this to higher environment where we have around `7 million` records, we're getting timed-out exceptions. Tried a few things, increase the response time-out in both `EXP API` and `SYS API` but no luck.

While ran following statement in DB (having 7 million records), it returns 100 records as per criteria in less than a second:

```
EXEC [dbo].[spGetCommodityReport] @factory = '0415', @filter = " city != '0099' ", @isoWYF  = "[202201]" , @isoWYT = "[202203]", @columns = "[202201], [202202], [202203]"
```

My question:
What is the best way to fix this time-out issue?

Comment: Unfortunately the question is not specific enough for this site. You need a specific technical question that has a single, objective answer.

Comment: @DaleK - main purpose of asking this question here, I am looking for a solution to optimise the code for performance. If this question does not fit for this site, could you please let me know relevant SO site or move this question to the best suited site for this question.

Comment: Are you deploying on cloudhub? What do you want to do with these records after fetching it? I mean does that action need to you process all the records as a whole? or can you split it? for example, maybe, You may want to write a CSV after it, or you have to send these records in batches to some external client?

Comment: BTW, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ is the site for architecture questions, however I do not see any mule related questions there yet

Comment: As I mentioned in my questions we are fetching paginated data max 100 records per page. These records need to be displayed in UI (external client is consuming API).

Comment: Ohh, I got it now. Have you tried to invoke the procedure manually using some other client? How long is it taking to execute.

Comment: Yes, mentioned in the question. Results are coming within a second.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the Mule application so you should provide details of the flows, configurations, versions (Mule, DB Connector, JDBC driver, DB version) and in this particular case a representative thread dump while the application is processing. It seems at first blush troubleshooting performance issues rather than a 'programming' question, so it may still be out of Stackoverflow scope anyway.

Comment: Additionally I strongly recommend to rephrase question 1) to focus on resolving the specific issue (timeout with large query) and to remove questions 2) and 3). Stackoverflow questions should be focused into a single issue and it is valid to get a question closed because of lack of focus. Question 2) is about DB usage mostly, independent of the specific issue mentioned in 1). Most likely it is an opinion based question so it is not valid either. Question 3 should be either implicit in 1 or too open. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: Thanks, I updated the original question.

Comment: Please add the details I asked about yesterday. Otherwise it is only possible to provide generic responses that not going to be very helpful.

Comment: @aled - we found the issue. We're using Synchronous calls and some time DB response is slow. We increased the response timeout for both SAPI and EAPI which resolved the issue. I will add my own answer here after few days. Currently, we're testing the fix.

Comment: SAP and EAPI where not mentioned in your question. This means the question was missing important information about the context of the issue.

Comment: SAPI and EAPI are mentioned in the question. We're not using Process API.